# Visual Basic Data Grid View - Count Average

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Okay, so I've got a datagrid view `DataGridView1` which is something like the below example.

```
Name         Points 
Jack           15 
zack           19 
Cody           05
```

I want to be able to count the average of all of the points, However the amount of points will be dynamic and change from time to time. So my solution must be able to work even if there's just two numbers and when there's upwards of 20.

I have been looking a round for a way of doing this, but most posts are only relevant if the amount of 'points' are static. And a lot of the solutions appear to be written in C++, which isn't too much use to a newbie coder like myself on Visual Basic.

So could anyone help me out here?

Comment: How do u get data into gridview? what the source?

Comment: the DGV has a `Count` property for the `.Rows` collection so you can code a loop to go thru them all without knowing how many rows there are in advance.  If it is bound to a datasource, that will have something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I would force it to draw a nice extra line in the data grid, by using a union select and a blanks for each column in the sqldatabind. This would add a nice row to the dataset be formatted as a totals row.. You may need to number the rows so your totals row is last most because of ordering. add the term 'Total' as a control in the results or handle it another way.

After that its just a bit of tweaking when your grid draws the row..
something like ...

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

Dim dRow As GridViewRow = sender
If dRow.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    If dRow.Cells(0).Text = "Total" Then
            Dim rx As Integer
            Dim TotalValue As Double = 0
            For rx = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 2
                TotalValue += CDbl(GridView1.Rows(rx).Cells(1).Text)
            Next
            dRow.Cells(1).Text = FormatNumber(TotalValue, 2)
        End If 
End If
```

End Sub